# C#: Unexpected character '$'

Tags: c#

I decompiled a C# assembly using ILSpy. Opened it as a project in VC. 

A small portion of the code throws errors that I don't know how to fix. Here's the code:

```
public static class CoroutineUtils
{
    [DebuggerHidden]
    public static IEnumerator WaitForRealSeconds(float time)
    {
        CoroutineUtils.<WaitForRealSeconds>c__Iterator2F <WaitForRealSeconds>c__Iterator2F = new CoroutineUtils.<WaitForRealSeconds>c__Iterator2F();
        <WaitForRealSeconds>c__Iterator2F.time = time;
        <WaitForRealSeconds>c__Iterator2F.<$>time = time;
        return <WaitForRealSeconds>c__Iterator2F;
    }
}
```

And here's the error: **Unexpected character '$'** (at line 8 in this case).

And if I open the .cs file in which the error appears, the compiler starts throwing a dozen more errors like **Identifier expected** at line 6 (right after "CoroutineUtils.")

Don't know what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just copy/paste decompiled code and be sure it will work. Compiler can use identifiers that are not valid in C# code but are valid in IL. It happens mostly for compiler generated code - automatic properties, anonymous types, iterators and `async`/`await` converted to state machines, etc. That's the case here.

It's really hard to say what the code is suppose to do, so it's really hard to say how to fix it.

Comment: The code in the question looks like a `yield return` iterator.

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean that ILSpy couldn't decompile the code completely, but other software might succeed? Or is this it?

Comment: I don't know. You could try.

Comment: @Bester I'm not aware of any CIL decompiler that can correctly convert the bytecode representation of a `yield return` function back into its source form. I don't suggest you let a tool do your job for you: if you're competent enough in C# you should be able to convert the bytecode back into C# yourself.